# Given two abitrary operators satisfying the canonical commutation relations at all times, can I show that they obey the same time evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, time-evolution

To be more clear: I take two operators, $A$ and $B$, which are functions of time, $A(t)$ and $B(t)$. I assume their time development to be unitary (but not neccessarily the same): $A$'s time evolution is generated by $H$, while $B$'s time evolution is (without loosing generality) generated by $H + D$. I want those time evolutions to satisfy the requirement that $A$ and $B$ satisfies the commutation relation:
$$
[A, B] = i
$$
At all times. The last thing I assume is that every other operator that can't be expressed as a function of $A$ and $B$ (for example because it acts on another subspace) is independent of $A$ and $B$ in the sense that it commutes with both of them.

I wanted to know wether it is possible to find a generator G that generates both time evolutions. My reasoning is as follows, but I don't know if it is correct:

I start at the Heisenberg equations (I only look at infinitesimal time evolutions, and I'm working in the Heisenberg-Picture. The time evolution may be time dependent, in that case $H$ and $D$ are to be seen as functions of time as well, evaluated at time $t= 0$
$$
A(\delta t) = A(0) - i \delta t[A(0), H] \\
B(\delta t) = B(0) - i \delta t[B(0), H + D]
$$

Now I require the commutation relation to hold:
$$
[A(\delta t), B(\delta t)] = [A(0), B(0)] -  \delta t ( [A(0), i [B(0), H+D]] + [i[A(0),H] , B(0)]) 
$$
I neglected orders of $\delta t^2$ here. 
If the CCR is still satisfied, then the terms proportional to $\delta t$ should vannish. That means:

$$
[A(0), i[B(0), H] + i[B(0), D]] = [B(0), i[A(0), H]]
$$
Now I use the jacobi-identity, the left-hand side evaluates to:
$$
i[[A(0), B(0)], H] + i[B(0), [A(0), H]] + i [[A(0), B(0)], D] + i[B(0), [A(0), D] \\ =  i[B(0), [A(0), H]] + i[B(0), [A(0), D]]
$$
Two of the terms vanish because the canonic commutation relation holds and an operator commutes with a number. 
Comparing with the right-hand-side, only one part remains:
$$
i[B(0), [A(0), D]] = 0
$$

There will be some kind of equation (possibly time dependent) that connects $D$ and $A(0)$, $B(0)$ at that time (I can always find such an equation):
$$
D = f(A(0), B(0))
$$
Dependencies to other operators might be there as well, but because I assume they commute with $A(0)$ and $B(0)$, I ommit them. Because of the last equation, f can't depend on terms that contain products of $A(0)$ and $B(0)$. 
$$
D = g(A(0)) + h(B(0))
$$
$H+D-h(B(0))$ would yield the same time evolution for $B(0)$, because $B(0)$ commutes with $h(B(0))$ and $H + g(A(0))$ would yield the same time evolution for $A$ as $H$ would. Both operators are the same, so I found an operator that generates the time evolutions for both the operators.

Is this reasoning correct? I am unsure about the part where I am using a function $f$ to describe the relations of the different operators.

EDIT: What I thought about: If I require the condition for $A$ and $B$ to hold in exponentiated form (Weyl-Relations), then the Stone-Von-Neumann Theorem holds for $A$ and $B$, which says that $A$ and $B$ are unique up unitary transformations. This means if I find $A(\delta t)$ and $B(\delta t)$ that satisfy the Weyl-Relations, they are related to $A(0)$ and $B(0)$ by one single a unitary Transformation.

For the usual form of the commutation relation, there isn't a result like the Stone-Von-Neumann-Theorem, so I won't necessarily, for $A(\delta t)$, $B(\delta t)$, $A(0)$ and $B(0)$ find a unitary Transformation relating the two, without additional conditions. However, I do impose an additional condition with the requirement that the two $A$'s and $B$'s are each related by an indidual unitary transformation (which holds only for $A$ or $B$ respectively).